# In German, to which of Nietzsche's books does the abbreviation "GA" refer to?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, nietzsche

I'm reading an academic article in German about Nietzsche and I really need to check the texts the author refers to, however I have no clue what "GA" refers to, even after checking the list of German titles of Nietzsche's books... Anyone have an idea?

In the link I gave an example of it, hope somebody can figure ou out!

Thanks :^)

[example in article](https://ibb.co/eeMf3y)

Comment: Maybe Collected Works (German : [Gesamtausgabe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Nietzsche#Werke_und_Ausgaben)).

Comment: Usual is Gesamtausgabe or Gesammelte Abhandlungen, but in this case it means: "die sogenannte Großoktavausgabe (heute übliche Sigle: GA)". https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nietzsche-Ausgabe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Nietzsche. I can only tell you that in German the abbreviation GA *usually* stands for “Gesamtausgabe” (= collected works).

According to this list [here](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/niet.2014.43.issue-1/nietzstu-2014-0138/nietzstu-2014-0138.xml) there's no single work by Nietzsche  which is abbreviated by “GA”. It would also be weird to do that, because of the confusion for German speakers: GA = “Gesamtausgabe” is a pretty standard abbreviation.